# Unbiased estimator help

Tags: probability, expectation, parameter-estimation

> A biased six faced die has probability $p$ of showing a 3 when it is tossed. The random variable $X$ is the number of tosses up to and including third 3
>
> (a) State the distribution of X
>
> (b) Find $P(X = x)$, $x>3$
>
> (c) Show that $Y = \frac{2}{(X-1)(X-2)}$ is an unbiased estimator of $p^2$

I've gotten the answers to (a) and (b), but I cannot solve (c). Anyone kind enough to provide a hint or the full length answer?

Comment: Multiply the result from b) by $Y$ and sum over $x$ to find the mean of the estimator. You should find $p^2$

Comment: Just to check, the answer from (b) is $P(X=x)=\binom{x-1}{2}p^3(1-p)^{x-3}$? Since $X$ follows $NB(3,p)$.

Comment: Yes but you need to rewrite $\binom{x-1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} (x-2) (x-1)$

Comment: Sorry, this is a very late comment but why is $\sum_{x=3}^∞ p^3(1-p)^{x-3} = p^2$?

Comment: $p^3(1-p)^{-3}\sum_{x=3}^{\infty}(1-p)^x$ Use geometric sum formula